# Java multithreading synchronization problem

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm having some issues with java multithreading, best explained on an example:

```
    class Thread1 extends Thread
    {
        boolean val=false;


        public void set()
        {       
            val=true;
        }


        public void run()
        {

        while (true)
        {

            if(val==true)
            {
                System.out.println("true");
                val=false;
            }

            try
            {
                sleep(1);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   

    }
}
```

So this is a simple class which is ran in a separate thread.

Now consider this case:
1) I start the thread in the class above
2) from some other thread I call the `Thread1.set()` function
3) the condition on the Thread1.run() function evaluates to true

Now, the thing is that if I remove the sleep(1) from the above code, this condition is never set to true.

So my question is: is there any other way I can interrupt the run() function so that
other functions may set the variables that would be used inside the run()function?
(I'm making a game on Android, so the openGL renderer runs in one thread and my game logic thread would run in another thread and I would like to sync them every frame or two),

Answer (score 4):

If only a single thread (i.e. one other than the thread reading it) is modifying `val`, then make it `volatile`.

Comment: Yes making it volatile is just one of the many solutions, but perhaps you can explain why this actually works and why thread.sleep() also seems to have some affect on the outcome.

Comment: I can explain the volatile part. `volatile` establishes  a `synchronizes-with` relationship between two threads. If thread T1 sees the value that thread T2 wrote on some volatile variable, then it's guaranteed that T1 will see all the previous writes made by T2, including those to non-volatile variables. I have already seen some people saying that if T2 writes to a volatile variable before T1 tries to read it, that T1 will ALWAYS read the value written by T2, but I think this is NOT true (I would like some clarification on this :-). Regarding the influence of `sleep`, beats me!

Answer (score 3):

Your boolean variable is not `volatile` which means there is no guarantee that two different threads are seeing the same value. By sleeping it the virtual machine might cause the value set from a different thread to become visible to the thread (this is a guess - nothing more), but this behavior should not be relied upon in any way. You should either use a `volatile` boolean variable or an `AtomicBoolean` class depending on your needs.